# Overlaying shapefile on ggmap

Tags: shapefile, coordinate-system, overlay, ggmap

I have a dataset of village boundaries in ESRI format.
with the following projection information,

```
GEOGCS["GCS_WGS_1984",DATUM["D_WGS_1984",SPHEROID["WGS_1984",6378137.0,298.257223563]],
PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.0],UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433],AUTHORITY["EPSG",4326]]
```

Then , I tried to overlay(with the help of ggplot) it on an image from google static maps using get_map in R(which is basically Google static maps).
For this village 'Chhajju Nagala',I clearly see an offset(village is actually to the lower left).

[image]

This problem is with many villages.
I want a general solution for all them.
Should I change the projection or towgs84 parameters?
What to do?

Comment: How far off is it? I can't see that shape in the underlying satellite imagery. Have you tried loading it into QGIS? Can you share your data, or at least one or two samples?

Comment: centroid is 1.04 km off. The red polygon is the shape file of 'Chhajju Nagala' from my dataset. Actually on the Google maps, village is outside my boundary(to the lower left in the image).

Comment: Any chance you can draw on your image to indicate where a point or two on your polygon should be on the map?

Comment: So can you or can't you give us a sample data set?

Comment: @Spacedman,I can't give the data. I don't know the correct polygon. All I know now is that is there is an offset(may not be just translational).So,I want to correct any projection issues between projection info given above and projection used by google static maps. I hope you are able to see that the village is outside the boundary.

Comment: Yes the village is outside the boundary but we have no way of knowing how far or in which direction this polygon needs to move. Have you tried installing QGIS, loading the shapefile in there and comparing with a background map? There can be differences in projection handling with QGIS and R. Also, make sure all your R spatial packages are up-to-date. That's about all we can do without some data. Can't you just save that *one* polygon somewhere for us to try?